# Looking for matches: same variable, different tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a database with 2 tables: researchers and students.

Both of the tables have a variable called lastname.

What I want to do is look for the entered lastname in both of the tables.

When im entering the command:

```
SELECT lastname 
    FROM researchers 
    OR students 
    WHERE lastname = $certain_variable
```

I will get the `error #105`2 making me aware of the variables being ambiguous.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Both of the tables or either of the tables?

Comment: The variable will be a username and I want to select the lastname. The issue here is that the usernames and lastnames are stored in 2 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: removed `LEFT JOIN` answer after clarification on question.

You could use a compound query:

```
SELECT all_lastnames.lastname FROM (
   SELECT lastname FROM students
   UNION
   SELECT lastname FROM researchers
) all_lastnames
WHERE lastname = $certain_variable
```

Basically what that does is select lastname from both tables into 1 "temporary table" (created by `UNION`) which is aliased as `all_lastnames`. You can then run a `SELECT` on the `all_lastnames` table

Comment: This worked for me, but only if the lastname was in the researchers table. Entering a lastname of a student resulted into showing 0 matches.

Comment: You say "I want to do is look for the entered lastname in both of the tables" -- do you mean to say "I want to do is look for the entered lastname in either of the tables?"

Comment: exactly. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You can use TABLENAME.LastName instead this will remove the ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have common lastname's between the two tables use

```
SELECT a.lastname FROM 
researches AS a 
LEFT JOIN students AS b ON (a.lastname=b.lastname)
WHERE a.lastname = '$var'
```

You need to tell the query what lastname you want (from researches or students)
that is why you need to specify tablename or tablealias.field.

If your tables dont have a common lastname values and you want to 
search them to see where you find last name you can use UNION :

```
SELECT 'found researches', lastname FROM researches WHERE lastname = '$var'
UNION
SELECT 'found student', lastname FROM students WHERE lastname = '$var'
```

Make sure you escape $var .